# How To Customize Image Grid

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, product-attribute, gallery

I want to add one column in the Magento image grid. Is it feasible to add one column which is called gallery order.

How can I do this grid customization without updating core files?

[image: Desired gallery display]

Please suggest me how to do it

Comment: which field you have to add?

Comment: You will find Gallery Order in above image

Comment: He's needing to write a module that adds an attribute to gallery images so he can get a sort order, then display it and use it in templates on the front end.

Answer (score 2):

## Table columns

The columns are hard coded in `catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml`, this template is used by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content` which again is created programmatically so you cannot affect it via layout XML.

The block has its own event `catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout` that's dispatched before rendering, so you can create an observer for it and change the template to a custom version there.

## Table content

You will notice that there is no loop to populate the actual data, just one dummy row. This row is used as a template by JavaScript to create the rows dynamically based on image data, which again may come from JSON data for the existing images as well as directly from new uploaded images. And here comes the complicated part: which fields are included is hard coded in `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` at multiple places. Have a look at the `Product.Gallery` class in there and search for places where `this.images` is used. This should point you in the right direction.